# Modify global variable in a function in php

Tags: php

Sounds like a simple thing, though I cannot find an answer to this.

I have a global variable `$test` that contains a empty string at first. 
Through one function, Id like to modify this global variable to contain
    "Test" for example. If I do the following, nothing happens:

```
$test="";

function modify() {
global $test;
$test="Test";
}
```

So how can I modify the global variable value from the function modify()?
    Thanks!

Comment: Start with __calling__ a function. I.e. `modify();`

Comment: the code is correct. there must be something else going on. are you sure you call modify() before accessing the changed $test variable.

Comment: @HimanshuRaval He's already using the `global` statement like that question says. How does closing it as a duplicate solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the function or echoing `$test` so your code does not really do anything. You set out what the function will do and assigned variable `$test` to be a blank string but did not execute the function or return the result of `$test`. This is basics of functions and something you could easily find by looking at the documentation.

```
$test="";

function modify() {
    global $test;
    $test="Test";
}

modify();
echo $test;
```

EDIT: for multiple files

FILE1

```
$test="";

function modify() {
    global $test;
    $test="Test";
}
```

FILE2

```
include 'file1.php';

modify();
echo $test;
```

Comment: Yes,This will only change the value of $test in same file but when I am trying to access $test in another .php file it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you including the file? If you set the function in file1 and then in file2 you include file1 and execute modify() and then echo it will show the new value of $test.

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I mean. In my example it echo's "Test" as required.

Comment: @coder Variables don't persist between different script executions. If you want to set a variable in one script and use it in another script, you need to use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = ""; 

function modify() { 
    $GLOBALS['x'] = "lorum ipsum"; 
}

modify(); 
echo $x;
```

Comment: How is this different from using the `global` declaration?